# Is hoisting only implemented in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I know that c/c++/java has no hoisting. 
But JavaScript has variable hoisting and function hoisting. 
What I want to know is, any other languages has hoisting implemented?

Comment: Python has the same thing going on:
https://foreigngods.com/blog/2013/09/14/26/python-exhibits-behavior-similar-to-javascripts-variable-hoisting/

Comment: This isn't the right place for such "discussion" type questions. Correct or incorrect answers are the currency of SO. This doesn't fit.

Comment: @spender well its not a discussion, all he/she is asking if other languages do the same thing... Yes...or...No

Comment: in javascript it's called scoping.

Comment: @DigitalJedi ergo, I provide a single counter example (Macromedia/Adobe ActionScript, for instance), the answer is accepted and we all move on? That isn't the motivation of this question at all.

Comment: but why scripting language wants this feature? while static compiled language does not?

Comment: @cso https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/562313394431078400 https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/33403701100154880

Comment: @spender I can`t really read the intention of the person who asked this, but the sentence "What I want to know is, any other languages has hoisting implemented?" is quite clear to me, so if you post "Yes" as answer Im glad to give you a vote up and we can all move on ;) as your comment definitly answers this question.

Comment: @cso JS was a quick and dirty endeavour. I'm sure, if Brandon Eich had forseen its scope and depth, he'd have spent more than 10 days on the initial release. It still carries much of that "quick and dirty" legacy (although you really should be using the lexically-scoped `const` and `let` nowdays).